# Using standalone pyQGIS application QgsApplication.initQgis() fails?

Tags: pyqgis

I'm trying to execute the following code on a windows 7 system:

```
import qgis.core as qc
qgis_path = "C:\Program Files\QGIS Lyon\apps\qgis"
qc.QgsApplication.setPrefixPath(qgis_path, True)
qc.QgsApplication.initQgis()
print "Successfully Initialised"
```

The qc.QgsApplication.initQgis() command causes python to stop working.  Can anyone help with the steps I need to diagnose this problem?

Some background:

- I've tried a number of different combinations of forward slashes, escaped backslashes etc.for the path and still get the same error;
- I've been developing the code (part of a larger application) on Linux, without problems;
- A long time ago, I tested the code on Windows and it worked OK.  At that time I had QGIS Dufour installed;
- I suspect it may have something to do with having the correct environment variables set, but have been unable to find a definitive guide on which and how these variables need to be set.

Answer (score 8):

It seems things changed to init PyQGIS but were not updated in the cookbook.

There is a discussion about [the issue](https://hub.qgis.org/issues/13494). Look at the bottom of the discussion mainly.

Be careful, it's only a hint. It may be related to your Windows path too (working on Linux mainly).

So, it should work with

```
from qgis.core import QgsApplication
qgis_path = "C:/Program Files/QGIS Lyon/apps/qgis"
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath(qgis_path, True)
qgs = QgsApplication(sys.argv, False)
qgs.initQgis()
```

Comment: You're welcome. Can you validate my answer as it seems to be the right one. Thanks