# Atlas export using Python: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'atlas'

Tags: python, pyqgis, atlas, qgis-print-layouts, atlas-generator

I'm trying to export my atlas layout named "Atlas_png", but are getting the error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'atlas' (line 27).
```

I have tried to use this examples:
[Exporting QGIS Atlas using PyQGIS (qgis.core)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/345352/exporting-qgis-atlas-using-pyqgis-qgis-core) ---- Error line 27:

```
# Open prepared layout that as atlas enabled and set
layout = project.layoutManager().layoutByName(layout_name)

# Export atlas
exporter = QgsLayoutExporter(layout)
settings = QgsLayoutExporter.ImageExportSettings()
exporter.exportToImage(layout.atlas(),output_folder, 'png', settings)
```

https://github.com/carey136/Standalone-Export-Atlas-QGIS3 ---- Error line 85:

```
QgsProject.instance().read(myProject)
myLayout = QgsProject.instance().layoutManager().layoutByName(layoutName)
myAtlas = myLayout.atlas()
myAtlasMap = myAtlas.layout()
```

I am  sure that there is a layout called "Atlas_png" in the qgs project. I can get the name when running printLayouts in the Python console directly in QGIS.

Every examples seems to work, except when I am running them.

Any leads?

Running Python 3.7.0 and QGIS 3.10.2

Comment: That is pretty strange. The first example you show is working perfectly when I test it (making sure that layout_name has the value of the name of an existing layout). Your error message tells that your layout variable has not been initalized. Just for a test, Try to make a new (blank) layout, set layout_name to the name of that layout and see what is happening.

Comment: Just be aware that layout names can contain spaces... You can also try to rename the layout you are working on, or, if you open the layout manager to rename the layout, you can copy out the layout name as qgis knows it.

Comment: I just created an empty layout called test, changed it in the script, but same error. It is very strange!

Comment: This are my paths and names:  project_path = 'C:Users\\test\\Documents\\names\\workfile3.qgs'
    output_folder = 'C:Users\\test\\Documents\\names\\Python_test'
    layout_name = 'test'

Comment: If you run it in the python terminal in qgis, what does it say if you just type 
layout
?

Comment: the project_path and output_folder should not matter for the error message you are getting. What is happening when you do the 'layout = project.layoutManager ... command?

Comment: print(projectLayoutManager) gives: qgis._core.QgsLayoutManager object at 0x0000027AC9C2AB88

Comment: That makes sense, but  what about your "layout" variable?

Comment: The layout names also comes out as exactly the names i have been trying. It can read them in python console,

Comment: To ask again, what happens when you do the


layout = project.layoutManager().layoutByName(layout_name)

command

Comment: layout = project.layoutManager().layoutByName('test') returns: <qgis._core.QgsPrintLayout object at 0x0000027AC9C2AAF8>

Comment: so it can read it in qgis python console, but not outside

Comment: This is still an in Standalone script at QGIS 3.22.1 version